# Retrieving data from a MS SQL 2012 table based on FK value from another table using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working on `MS SQL Server 2012`. I have two tables - `Associates` and `Clients` and they have `M:N` relation so I have another table `MapClientToAssociates` where I have two foreign keys - `ClientID` and `AssociateID`. What I want to achieve is by providing a `ClientID` to take all the `AssociateID's` for this `Client` and then take all the information about each `Associate` (As I wrote, the relation is `M:N` so there can be several `Associates` for a certain client) and I want to return this data.

So basically I want to return rows containing :

```
`ID` - from `MapClientToAssociates`
`ClientID` - from `MapClientToAssociates`
`AssociateID` - from `MapClientToAssociates`
[column1] - from `Associates` (based on the `AssociateID` value)
[column2] - from `Associates` (based on the `AssociateID` value)
.
.
.
[columnN] - from `Associates` (based on the `AssociateID` value)
```

I tried to follow an existing code that is doing something pretty similar to that :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ClientGetAssociates] 
    @ClientID int
AS
BEGIN

    If Exists (Select * From dbo.MapClientToAssociates map Where map.ClientID = @ClientID)
    Begin

        Declare @AssociateID int = (Select * map.AssociateID From dbo.MapClientToAssociates map Where map.ClientID = @ClientID)
```

And I get an error that I don't understand at the very beginning - `Declare @AssociateID int = (Select * map.AssociateID` - here `map.AssociateID` map is underscored in red saying `Incorrect syntax near map`) but I have to admit I don't have any experience with `T-SQL` or writing stored procedures and this seems like a standard stuff for a sproc to do so I would appreciate any help to make this sproc working and hopefully later I'll have the time to examine how exactly the code is working, but for now the most important thing for me is to make the sproc returns the result I want.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  2005 I am assuming?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I thought it's getting clear from the title. The `SQL Server` is 2012 but I'm working on a very old project and I'm trying to get use of some sproc which maybe were created originally for 2005, dunno about that. But now it's 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This clause `(Select * map.AssociateID From dbo.MapClientToAssociates map Where map.ClientID = @ClientID)` is returning a derived *table* of integer values.  You are trying to assign it to a scalar (single) integer value, which does not make sense.

As for the actual syntax error, this :

```
Select * map.AssociateID From dbo.MapClientToAssociates map Where map.ClientID = @ClientID
```

is invalid because you would need to either remove the `*` or put a comma between it and the `map.AssociateID`.

---

This is how I would write this myself:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ClientGetAssociates] 
    @ClientID int
AS
BEGIN

    Select      act.*
    From        dbo.MapClientToAssociates map
    Left Join   dbo.Associates as act   ON act.AssociateID = map.AssociateID
    Where       map.ClientID = @ClientID)

End
```

Unless I needed to consume the returned rowset in another SQL procedure or expression, then I would write it as a table-valued function instead.

Comment: Yeah, this is a little misleading. In fact my idea with this code snippet was to show that I am unable to write this sproc myself because even the first few lines are giving me an error. Perfectly I need an entire code that is doing what I've described in my post.

Comment: I got this error :Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_Client_GetMappedAssociates, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.` any idea why? I see the closing bracket and there's no opening one..

Comment: Ok, I got it, I had a syntax error on my own and removing the bracket at the end of `Where` clause all went OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ClientGetAssociates] 
    @ClientID int
AS
BEGIN

    Select map.*, ass.*
    from dbo.MapClientToAssociates map, dbo.Associates ass
    where ass.AssociateID = map.AssociateID
    and map.ClientID = @ClientID
```

If this response is wrong, can you provide a script for create and populate table and the full code of stored procedure?